# Is it possible to extend a suspend function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How to extend a function that supports coroutines?

What I have right now:

```
class MyClass : (String, String) -> Int {
    override fun invoke(username: String, password: String): Int {
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

What I'd like to have:

```
class MyClass : (String, String) -> Int {
    override suspend fun invoke(username: String, password: String): Int {
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

Is that possible without an explicit definition of function as a Functional interface?

Comment: Do you mean `class MyClass : suspend (String, String) -> Int`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman right, but it's not supported yet, the compiler isn't able to compile this construction. At least from that I found.

Comment: Certainly, but even when it's supported, you're going to need that `suspend` keyword.

Comment: That is exactly I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now supported to extend your class to `class MyClass: suspend -> Unit`

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/08/kotlin-1-5-30-released/?utm_source=slack&utm_medium=announcement&utm_campaign=1-5-30-release

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported yet and is going to be supported in kotlin 1.6

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18707